# Where is the Bounty?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

From [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/22896/3940) question I started a bounty that ended recently. After the bounty started  user [luri](https://askubuntu.com/users/8851/luri) edited his answer to give a most useful additional information that made me award the bounty. However [luri's reputation score](https://askubuntu.com/users/8851/luri?tab=reputation) obviously did not change. Where did the bounty go? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the bounties you start show up in the rep graph.

Comment: it would be nice to have +bounties show up as well ;)

Comment: Yes, I agree. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ty, Takkat, but (even though I haven't been closely watching my reputation), I'd swear it did increase. Is there any way to compute it so that I can check that?

Comment: Go to your user page and check from "reputation" what rep you got for the answer. It says 45 (3 up votes 1 accept). The +50 bounty is missing.

Comment: Rep from bounty may be missing in the reputation stats. But also if you look at your rep graph there seems not to be a +50 increase at the date the bounty was awarded. However the graph is not very precise and if you say your rep increased by +50 then it may only not be clearly visible from the graph.

Comment: You should see a (50) for the question on http://askubuntu.com/reputation

Comment: I have this in askubuntu.com/reputation: 9     22901 (50), that's on Feb 5th.. so I guess it did increase. But the fact is that, as Takkat points out, the graph is under 600, when my rep is over 650. So it's kind of weird. As I said, I'm not watching my rep or keeping track of it, so I don't know if the graph has always been behind the "real" number....